# Get string except first sentence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm creating a simple blog with Rails and I want one field to edit to post stuff.

The first sentence will be the title and the rest will be the body.

I'm using this to get the first line of a post:

```
=article.content.split('.')[0]
```

But how do I get the rest of if for the body - minus the first sentence.

```
=article.content - THE FIRST SENTENCE
```

**Update**

This almost works:

```
=article.content.split('.')[1..-1].join('.')
```

But the last period of the content (if there is one) is omitted.

Comment: Please save yourself for unnecessary work to create a "title" field for the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- i = article.content.index('.')

= article.content[0..i-1] # title
= article.content[i+1..-1] # content
```

Comment: Yep. Except that the last period (if there is one) is left off.

Comment: Thanks! BTW `=article.content.split('. ')[1..-1].join('.')` worked. I just look for the first '. ' instead of '.'

Answer (score 0):

Getting the first sentence is not a decent use case. Yes I would go with creating a separate field for title or,

**Get the first 50 chars of the content with a ... appended to it.**

In rails, use this helper.

```
truncate(article.content, length: 50)
```